# Heroku inquiry, running a Java application on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, maven-3

I am trying to deploy and run a Java application on Heroku. It is a small application. And it comes with a database.

Questions:
on the Heroku website tutorial, it requires having Maven 3 installed. 
Only Maven web application runs on Heroku? How about a non-Maven Jave EE application?

The application is just a simple RESTful web service. After push the application to Heroku, it is not running. 
It seems to me that a database has been created. But it showed error when tried to open the app. Do I have to create another database and do some configuration?

I am new to this and have no clue. Can anybody shed some lights on this?
Thanks.

When I try to `heroku ps:scale web=1`
it returns

```
Scaling dynos... failed" ! No such process type web defined in Procifile.**
```

What is `Procifile` and where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What is Procfile and where is it?*

The `Procfile` tells Heroku how to start the different processes for your application (web, worker, etc). You define it at the root of your project. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#define-a-procfile

*Only Maven web application runs on Heroku? How about a non-Maven Jave EE application?*

The Maven dependency is about being able to build the application; it is not a strict requirement, as Heroku supports builds with different "build packs", including Gradle. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

That said, if you still want/need to use a tool to build a `.war` locally, you can deploy that directly. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment

In general, though, your life will be easier if you follow the practices outlined in the article [Getting Started with Java on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction) because the Heroku framework implements [12 Factor](http://12factor.net) architecture, which enforces simplifying constraints on your architecture, and encourages automation and repeatability in builds and deployments.